# Works great in all browsers except Firefox

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do a simple thing in HTML and CSS but for some reason it doesn't work good in Firefox.
This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        #list{
            width:100%;
            min-height:27px;
            position:absolute;
        }
        .listBTN{
            width:20px;
            height:20px;
            background:url(list.png) no-repeat center center;
            float:left;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="list">
    <div class="listBTN"></div>
    <div class="listBTN"></div>
    <div class="listBTN"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem:
[image]

Comment: Use a doctype if you're not doing it already.

Comment: You should name that “simple thing” in question title and explain it verbally in the question. Otherwise, people who have a similar problem will hardly find this question and its answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks like a browser zoom issue. Make sure your Firefox isn't zoomed out: hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> to reset it to 100%.